# Flutter Desktop Application Image Picker

Tags: flutter-web

I am building Flutter Desktop Application . I am facing many issues .
I want to pick a image from Flutter desktop and need path in return But no plugins are supported .
Help me regarding this issue .I hope you will reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you use file_picker pub its  support  for the flutter Desktop its also return file path

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.